# WordPress: Function for loading a specific page with shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have this structure of pages in WordPress:

```
Materials //parent
-> Plastic //children
-> Metal //children
-> ...
```

I want to include content from my file `grid-fasads.php` with shortcode exactly where I need to.

I have this code in a **product.php** where I use a shortcode:

```
$fasads = get_field('fasad_type');                                                          
foreach ($fasads as $f) {                            
     echo do_shortcode('[grid-fasad]');                            
}
```

I wrote this function in **functions.php**:

```
function get_fasads($atts, $content = null ) {

   $my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
   $all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query( array( 'post_type' => 'page' ) );

   // get a specific page ID
   $materials =  get_page( 4702 );

   // filter for choosing a children pages of 'materials'
   $materials_children = get_page_children( $materials->ID, $all_wp_pages );

   foreach ( $materials_children as $children ) {
         $page = $children->ID;
         echo $page;
  }

  // It's ok. The pages IDs are shown.
  // After that I have this:

    $recent = new WP_Query( "page_id = " . $page );
    while( $recent->have_posts() ) : $recent->the_post();
        require( '/fasads/grid-fasads.php' );
        the_content();
    endwhile;        
} 

add_shortcode( 'grid-fasad','get_fasads' );
```

I understand that the problem is `( "page_id = " .  $page)`. I need to include a .php file's content for each children pages of 'Materials' page. Tried to insert last part of code into a loop, but failed every time.

Here is a fragment from

I also tried this loop:

```
foreach ($materials_children as $children) {        
    $page = $children->ID;                 
    $recent = new WP_Query("page_id=".$page);
    while ($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
        require('/fasads/grid-fasads.php');
        the_content();        
    endwhile;          
    print_r(array_count_values((array)$page));
}
```

But as a result it shows a duplicates of values. Something is wrong.

Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem.

Here is a function:

```
function get_pallette() {
$my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
$all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page'));

// get a specific page ID
$materials =  get_page_by_title('Materials');                        
$materials_children = get_page_children( $materials->ID, $all_wp_pages );

if (isset ($materials_children)) :                             
    foreach ($materials_children as $children) {        
        $page = $children->ID;             
    }         
    $fasads = get_field('fasad_type');                                                                                      
    if (isset ($fasads)) :
        foreach ($fasads as $f) {
            $p = get_page_by_title( $f );                            
            if (!empty ($p)) :                                 
                echo do_shortcode("[grid-fasad page=\"$p->ID\"]");                     
            else : 
                //do something;
            endif;
        }
    else : 
        //do something;;
    endif;             
 endif; 
 //do something;
}
```

And here is another function for a generating shortcode:

```
function get_fasads($atts, $content = null ){               

$atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'page' => 0  
    ), $atts, 'grid-fasad');    
$recent = new WP_Query('page_id='. $atts['page']);
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-content/themes/theme/fasads/grid-fasads.php';        
while ($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
    require $path;                 
endwhile;         
}      

add_shortcode('grid-fasad','get_fasads');
```

A good's page fragment:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); global $_product; $_product = new jigoshop_product( $post->ID ); ?>
<div id="post-<?php $id_page ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>            
<div class="summary">                                                                                      
    <?php  do_action('jigoshop_after_single_product_summary', $post, $_product); ?>  
    ...
    <?php get_pallette(); ?>                    
</div>  
 <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Maybe it's not an elegant decision, but it works. 
There is only 1 problem still: after execution function get_pallette() the page loose it's own ID, because I'm using "new WP_Query" with a new IDs of page's children. And if this function goes before action "jigoshop_after_single_product_summary" (as I want to), it cannot load a content of an actual good's page.